# Timing a page loader only to visible images using imagesLoaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loader

I think I'm very close to figuring this out but I'm not proficient at javascript and jquery. The solution I am trying to use is imagesLoaded (http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/).

Essentially, I want a page with large modal content (hidden on page load) to appear to load much faster. In other words, I want the loader (grey overlay with spinner) to clear when the visible images have loaded even though the modal images continue to load in the background.

My strategy is to create a div in the html and place a copy of each visible image within it. In my CSS I style this div as 'display: none;' and perhaps position it '-9999' top and left. So this div will load the images but never draw on screen.

Now, I want to trigger the '.fadeOut' function for the loader elements with imagesLoaded, assigned to the above div. That way the UI will appear ready while the remaining hidden modal images finish loading.

I'm trying this is jquery as follows:

```js
<script>

$('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
 $(".spinner").fadeOut("slow");
 $(".spinnerwrapper").fadeOut("slow");
} );

</script>
```

```css
.loader {
 position: fixed;
 top: 77px;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity:0.80;
 filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 900;
}

 #container {
 position: fixed;
 display:none;
 left: -9999px;
 top: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<!-- page header -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script></head>

<div id="spinnerwrapper">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="loader"></div>

<!-- visible page content -->

<div id="container">
 <img src="images/image_1.jpg">
    <img src="images/image_2.jpg">
    <img src="images/image_3.jpg">
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
</body>

<!-- hidden modal content -->
```

I'm almost certain my syntax is wrong there. I'm just learning the basics of scripting. Can anybody work this out? Or provide an aternate solution?

Comment: Getting error message: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function

Comment: Can you explain why you use left: -9999px; & top: -9999px; ?? in container ID?? and the other question is  why using  spinnerwrapper ,spinner div ?? And the main problem you write the script wrong . you set the Container  ID display none via css. But you don't  make it show after the loader fadeout. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/tmqsd8uo/ ]

Answer (score 0):

To trigger something like a `.fadeOut()`, you can use it like this:

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded({
  // options...
  },
  function() {
        $('.fade-it').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Check out the fiddle to see it fire: https://jsfiddle.net/qx5eoo3j/

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your JS, try this:

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded( {}, function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".spinner").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".spinnerwrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    $('#container').show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sh65j0a/4/)

Comment: I still get the message: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function    Does this mean the script source link is incorrect?

Comment: It means that imageLoaded is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.(I just add sample image more then 3) 
Remove Elements are[position:fixed; left: -9999px; & top: -9999px; from css #container  spinnerwrapper ,spinner DIV from html part. Because I don't see any uses of those]. If you have any questions about this answer ask me in comment. [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/tmqsd8uo/2/)

```js
$('#container').imagesLoaded(function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
  $('#container').show();
});
```

```css
  .loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 900;
  }
  
  #container {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="loader"></div>

<!-- visible page content -->

 <div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
 <!-- etc -->
</div>
   </body>
```